# Trying to ID a sci fi show from perhaps mid 90s? Martian invasion beat with love?

Tags: story-identification, aliens, alien-invasion, love

I remember Martians (looked like humans) with weapons landing is an assault craft of some sort and humans basically welcoming them/hugging kissing them. The main character, a Martian is sad because it is the end of his civilization/way of life. At least how I remember it. Could have been a episode of of a series.

Comment: This almost sounds like a warped description of [Mars Attacks! (1996)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0116996/), but while love was attempted to stop the invasion it did not have the intended outcome.

Comment: Earth Girls Are Easy? It isn't martians but sounds kind of similar.

Comment: What kind of "show"? Movie, TV, stage play, opera?

Answer (score 1):

By the description, I think this is ["The Ray Bradbury Theatre"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ray_Bradbury_Theater) S05E05 "The Concrete Mixer"

The [IMDB synopsis](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0683208/plotsummary?ref_=tt_ov_pl) says:

> An invasion force from Mars heads to Earth, prepared to overcome a strong military resistance. Instead, when they arrive they are greeted by glad-handing community representatives, a marching band, and the key to the city. The aliens are soon introduced to the vulgar and consumer-oriented "American way of life" which turns out to be a bigger threat than an armed resistance would have been.

This episode aired in January 1992, so it fits the timeframe.

Thhe full episode is available on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0YLqJEODYVk)